# Exchange 2016 ActiveSync error

Tags: exchange, exchange-2016, activesync

I'm trying to verify if all Exchange virtual directory are configured properly and running.

I try to use Browser to surf https://hostname.company.com/Microsoft-Server-ActiveSync, however it returned error http 505

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXM1r.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go into IIS and under the Active Sync virtual directory, under the Proxy sub directory, add the Negotiate provider within Windows Authentication. [Similar thread](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2099181-exchange-2010-and-2016-coesxistence-weird-activesync-issue) for your reference.

You can also remake Active Sync Web Site and reconfigure ExternalURL and SSL Settings, using [Remove-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/client-access-servers/remove-activesyncvirtualdirectory?view=exchange-ps) and [New-ActiveSyncVirtualDirectory](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/client-access-servers/new-activesyncvirtualdirectory?view=exchange-ps), according to this [similar issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/80e70324-d35e-4ce0-b69c-5ada1bfbe607/active-sync-error-http-501505-exchange-2010-sp1?forum=exchangesvrgenerallegacy).

Comment: Hi, what's going on with your problem now?